# I got error running migration under priject I added into homestead?

Tags: homestead

I added new project with migration files into homestead
and I added new database name :

```
databases:
   ...
    - ProjectName

ports:
    - send: 33060 # MySQL/MariaDB
    to: 3306
```

In .env I added all connect parameters:

After I entered vagrant bash I got error running migration:

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=ProjectName
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

```
$ php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]  (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ProjectName and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:712
    708▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    709▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    710▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    711▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 712▕             throw new QueryException(
    713▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    714▕             );
    715▕         }
    716▕     }

      +33 vendor frames 
  34  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I have a ProjectName database in my homestaead phpmyadmin. I copypasted migrations table from other project, but I still got this error...
How to fix it ?
I cleared cahch with command :

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Seems I have valid ports set. How can I check it additively ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I set invalid passport. Must be :

```
  DB_PASSWORD=secret
```